# Why won't .click() assign a value to my variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm *VERY* new to coding. After a week and a half on Codeacademy I'm trying to create something to piece everything I've learned together. Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){


//What img does when mouse hovers on it
    $("img").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).css("height", "10em");
        $(this).css("width", "10em");
        $("selector").css("cursor", "pointer");
    });
    $("img").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).css("height", "8em");
        $(this).css("width", "8em");
    });
    
    
    
//Assigning values to userChoice (click on an img!)
    $('.rock').click(function() {
        var userChoice = "rock";
        var compChoice = Math.random();
    });
    
    $('.paper').click(function() {
        var userChoice = "paper";
        var compChoice = Math.random();
    });  
    
    $('.scissors').click(function() {
        var userChoice = "scissors";
        var compChoice = Math.random();
    });    
    
    $('.lizard').click(function() {
        var userChoice = "lizard";
        var compChoice = Math.random();
    });    
    
    $('.spock').click(function() {
        var userChoice = "rock";
        var compChoice = Math.random();
    });
    
        
//Assign compChoice
    if (compChoice <= 0.20) {
     compChoice = "rock";
    } else if(compChoice <= 0.40) {
     compChoice = "paper";
    } else if(compChoice <= 0.60) {
     compChoice = "scissors";
    } else if(compChoice <= 0.80) {
        compChoice = "lizard";
    } else {
        compChoice = "spock";
    }

    
 
    if (userChoice === compChoice) {
        $("#end").css("display", "inline");
        $("#outcome").text(userChoice + " against " + compChoice + " ?");
        $("#winner").text("It's a tie!");
    }
    else if (userChoice === "rock") {
        if (compChoice === "paper") {
            $("#end").css("display", "inline");
            $("#outcome").text("PAPER covers ROCK!");
            $("#winner").text("You LOSE!");
        }
        else if (compChoice === "scissors") {
            $("#end").css("display", "inline");
            $("#outcome").text("ROCK crushes SCISSORS!");
            $("#winner").text("You WIN!");
        }
        else if (compChoice === "lizard") {
            $("#end").css("display", "inline");
            $("#outcome").text("ROCK crushes LIZARD!");
            $("#winner").text("You WIN!");
        }
        else {
            $("#end").css("display", "inline");
            $("#outcome").text("SPOCK vaporizes ROCK!");
            $("#winner").text("You LOSE!");
        }
    }
    else if (userChoice === "paper") {
        if (compChoice === "rock") {
            $("#end").css("display", "inline");
            $("#outcome").text("PAPER covers ROCK!");
            $("#winner").text("You WIN!");
        }
        else if (compChoice === "scissors") {
            $("#end").css("display", "inline");
            $("#outcome").text("SCISSORS cuts PAPER!");
            $("#winner").text("You LOSE!");
        }
        else if (compChoice === "lizard") {
            $("#end").css("display", "inline");
            $("#outcome").text("LIZARD eats PAPER!");
            $("#winner").text("You LOSE!");
        }
        else {
            $("#end").css("display", "inline");
            $("#outcome").text("PAPER disproves SPOCK!");
            $("#winner").text("You WIN!");
        }
    }
    else if (userChoice === "scissors") {
        if (compChoice === "rock") {
            $("#end").css("display", "inline");
            $("#outcome").text("ROCK crushes SCISSORS!");
            $("#winner").text("You LOSE!");
        }
        else if (compChoice === "paper") {
            $("#end").css("display", "inline");
            $("#outcome").text("SCISSORS cuts PAPER!");
            $("#winner").text("You WIN!");
        }
        else if (compChoice === "lizard") {
            $("#end").css("display", "inline");
            $("#outcome").text("SCISSORS decapitate LIZARD!");
            $("#winner").text("You WIN!");
        }
        else {
            $("#end").css("display", "inline");
            $("#outcome").text("SPOCK smashes SCISSORS!");
            $("#winner").text("You LOSE!");
        }
    }
    else if (userChoice === "lizard") {
        if (compChoice === "rock") {
            $("#end").css("display", "inline");
            $("#outcome").text("ROCK crushes LIZARD!");
            $("#winner").text("You LOSE!");
        }
        else if (compChoice === "paper") {
            $("#end").css("display", "inline");
            $("#outcome").text("LIZARD eats PAPER!");
            $("#winner").text("You WIN!");
        }
        else if (compChoice === "scissors") {
            $("#end").css("display", "inline");
            $("#outcome").text("SCISSORS decapitate LIZARD!");
            $("#winner").text("You LOSE!");
        }
        else {
            $("#end").css("display", "inline");
            $("#outcome").text("LIZARD poisons SPOCK!");
            $("#winner").text("You WIN!");
        }
    }
    else {
        if (compChoice === "rock") {
            $("#end").css("display", "inline");
            $("#outcome").text("SPOCK vaporizes ROCK!");
            $("#winner").text("You WIN!");
        }
        else if (compChoice === "paper") {
            $("#end").css("display", "inline");
            $("#outcome").text("PAPER disproves SPOCK!");
            $("#winner").text("You LOSE!");
        }
        else if (compChoice === "scissors") {
            $("#end").css("display", "inline");
            $("#outcome").text("SPOCK smashes SCISSORS!");
            $("#winner").text("You WIN!");
        }
        else {
            $("#end").css("display", "inline");
            $("#outcome").text("LIZARD poisons SPOCK!");
            $("#winner").text("You LOSE!");
        }    
    };
});
```

```css
img {
    display: block;
 height: 8em;
 width: 8em;
 border-radius: 100%;
 border: 0.2em solid #001F5C;
 margin: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

.title {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #001F5C;
    height: 4em;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 0.5em;
    border: 0;
    font-family: "Arial";
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #CCD2DE;
}

.main {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #8099CC;
    height: 40em;
    margin-top: -2em;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}

.options {
    position: relative;
    width: 20em;
    height: 20em;
    padding: 4em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 1.75em auto 0;
}

.options div {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; left: 40%;
    margin: -2em;
    z-index: 1;
}


#end {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #CCD2DE;
    border: 0.2em solid #A3A8B2;
    padding: 0;
    border-radius: 5%;
    height: 7em;
    width: 8em;
    top: 35%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -4em;
    margin-top: -1em;
    z-index: 1000;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #001F5C;
    font-size: 3em;
}

#last {
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #001F5C;
    font-size: 1em;
}

.rock { transform: rotate(216deg) translate(10em); rotate(-216deg);}
.paper { transform: rotate(288deg) translate(10em) rotate(-288deg); }
.scissors { transform: rotate(360deg) translate(10em) rotate(-360deg); }
.lizard { transform: rotate(72deg) translate(10em) rotate(-72deg); }
.spock { transform: rotate(144deg) translate(10em) rotate(-144deg); }

**JavaScript**
```

```html
**HTML**

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Rock Paper Scissors Lizard Spock</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="title">
        <h2>ROCK  |  PAPER  |  SCISSORS  |  LIZARD  | SPOCK</h2>
    </div>
    
    <div class="main">
        <div id="end">
            <p id="outcome">SPOCK smashes SCISSORS!</p>
            <p id="winner">You win !</p>
            <p><span style="font-size:20px">Click here to play again!</span></p>
        </div>
    <div class="options">
        <div class="rock">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b1/The_Childrens_Museum_of_Indianapolis_-_Petoskey_stone.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <div class="paper">
            <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2013/07/18/10/57/note-paper-163603_640.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <div class="scissors">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/29/Small_pair_of_blue_scissors.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <div class="lizard">
            <img src="http://www.torange.us/photo/10/16/Water-lizard-agama-1326212612_65.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <div class="spock">
            <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8566/16477696740_cfb9ccddbc.jpg"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>

**CSS**
```

I've tested and retested and I think the problem is that the .click() function is not assigning new values to the "userChoice" variable. But I don't know what's wrong with my code.

If you know what's wrong, I'd greatly appreciate a nudge in the right direction or some kind of clue! I really want to learn.

Comment: Your variables are not global. they are local to the event handler and not accessible outside.

Comment: What is your error? It will help people figure out the problem.

Comment: Hello, Trying to clean up unanswered question. Please mark accept an answer if it has solved your problem.

Comment: As all have said it's all about scope. A variable only exists inside the function in which it's declared. 'var userChoice' declares the variable. If you declare it inside the click event handler it doesn't exist outside the click event handler. If you declare it inside the $(document).ready function it doesn't exist outside that function. if you declare it after the <script> tag but not inside any function it's now global and can be used anywhere.

Comment: You should also realize that your click event handlers stop as soon as you close the function. So your click event handlers are assigning values to local variables, then ending. Your code to assign compChoice and output the winner only gets called once when the document is ready because it's inside your $(document).ready function. You should create that code as a separate function outside of your $(document).ready function and call that function from inside your click event handlers. http://jsfiddle.net/gunvyecg/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making the checks for userChoice and compChoice in document ready and on document ready you haven't clicked anything. So in every click you should call a function for the checks where you will send the variables:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var userChoice = '', compChoice = 0;
    $('.rock').click(function() {
        userChoice = "rock";
        compChoice = Math.random();

        checkElement(userChoice, compChoice);
    });
    $('.paper').click(function() {
        userChoice = "paper";
        compChoice = Math.random();

        checkElement(userChoice, compChoice);
    });  

    $('.scissors').click(function() {
        userChoice = "scissors";
        compChoice = Math.random();

        checkElement(userChoice, compChoice);
    });    

    $('.lizard').click(function() {
        userChoice = "lizard";
        compChoice = Math.random();

        checkElement(userChoice, compChoice);
    });    

    $('.spock').click(function() {
        userChoice = "rock";
        compChoice = Math.random();

        checkElement(userChoice, compChoice);
    });
});

function checkElement(userChoice, compChoice){
    if (compChoice <= 0.20) {
        compChoice = "rock";
    } else if(compChoice <= 0.40) {
    compChoice = "paper";
    } else if(compChoice <= 0.60) {
        compChoice = "scissors";
    } else if(compChoice <= 0.80) {
        compChoice = "lizard";
    } else {
        compChoice = "spock";
    }



    if (userChoice === compChoice) {
        $("#end").css("display", "inline");
        $("#outcome").text(userChoice + " against " + compChoice + " ?");
        $("#winner").text("It's a tie!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense... so basically I'm running the rest of the code (if/else statement for compChoice, if/else for the outcome) everytime I click? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Please vote and approve my answer if it has helped you.

Answer (score 3):

You have a scope issue, move the variable declaration outside the click handlers, and just set the value inside the handlers:

```
var userChoice = "", compChoice = 0;
$('.rock').click(function() {
    userChoice = "rock";
    compChoice = Math.random();
});

$('.paper').click(function() {
    userChoice = "paper";
    compChoice = Math.random();
});  

$('.scissors').click(function() {
    userChoice = "scissors";
    compChoice = Math.random();
});    

$('.lizard').click(function() {
    userChoice = "lizard";
    compChoice = Math.random();
});    

$('.spock').click(function() {
    userChoice = "rock";
    compChoice = Math.random();
});
```

Comment: This definitely helped, until I added more code afterward. But I think someone else below has answered that question! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You are redefining the var `userChoice` and `compChoice` on each click, and those variables are only valid on the scope of each function.

You should define it as a global variable.

Comment: To be fair, this is the correct answer and was 2 mins before mine ;) +1

Answer (score 1):

It's a scope issue... you have declared the userChoice and compChoice locally in each click binding.... try this

**EDIT:** or even better, give them an ID instead and wrap it all up in one binding :-)

```
var userChoice = "", compChoice = 0;

//Assigning values to userChoice (click on an img!)
$('#rock, #paper, #scissors, #lizard, #spock').on('click', function() {
    userChoice = $(this).id;
    compChoice = Math.random();
});
```

Just because I was bored, and I like neat code... I have refactored it :-)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //What img does when mouse hovers on it
    $("img").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).css("height", "10em")
        $(this).css("width", "10em")
        $("selector").css("cursor", "pointer")
    })

    $("img").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).css("height", "8em")
        $(this).css("width", "8em")
    })

    var userChoice = "", compChoice = 0

    // Assigning values to userChoice (click on an img!)
    $('#rock, #paper, #scissors, #lizard, #spock').on('click', function() {
        userChoice = $(this).id
        compChoice = Math.random()
    })

    // Assign compChoice
    if (compChoice <= 0.20) 
        compChoice = "rock"

    else if(compChoice <= 0.40)
        compChoice = "paper"

    else if(compChoice <= 0.60)
        compChoice = "scissors"

    else if(compChoice <= 0.80) 
        compChoice = "lizard"
    else 
        compChoice = "spock"


    if (userChoice === compChoice) 
    {
        $("#end").css("display", "inline")
        $("#outcome").text(userChoice + " against " + compChoice + " ?")
        $("#winner").text("It's a tie!")
    }
    else if (userChoice === "rock") 
    {
        switch(compChoice)
        {
            case "paper":
                $("#end").css("display", "inline")
                $("#outcome").text("PAPER covers ROCK!")
                $("#winner").text("You LOSE!")
            break

            case "scissors":
                $("#end").css("display", "inline")
                $("#outcome").text("ROCK crushes SCISSORS!")
                $("#winner").text("You WIN!")
            break

            case "lizard":
                $("#end").css("display", "inline")
                $("#outcome").text("ROCK crushes LIZARD!")
                $("#winner").text("You WIN!")
            break

            default:
                $("#end").css("display", "inline")
                $("#outcome").text("SPOCK vaporizes ROCK!")
                $("#winner").text("You LOSE!")
            break
        }
    }
    else if (userChoice === "paper") 
    {
        switch(compChoice) 
        {
            case "rock":
                $("#end").css("display", "inline")
                $("#outcome").text("PAPER covers ROCK!")
                $("#winner").text("You WIN!")
            break

            case "scissors":
                $("#end").css("display", "inline")
                $("#outcome").text("SCISSORS cuts PAPER!")
                $("#winner").text("You LOSE!")
            break

            case "lizard":
                $("#end").css("display", "inline")
                $("#outcome").text("LIZARD eats PAPER!")
                $("#winner").text("You LOSE!")
            break

            default: 
                $("#end").css("display", "inline")
                $("#outcome").text("PAPER disproves SPOCK!")
                $("#winner").text("You WIN!")
        }
    }
    else if (userChoice === "scissors") 
    {
        switch(compChoice) 
        {
            case "scissors":
                $("#end").css("display", "inline")
                $("#outcome").text("ROCK crushes SCISSORS!")
                $("#winner").text("You LOSE!")
            break

            case "paper":
                $("#end").css("display", "inline")
                $("#outcome").text("SCISSORS cuts PAPER!")
                $("#winner").text("You WIN!")
            break

            case "lizard":
                $("#end").css("display", "inline")
                $("#outcome").text("SCISSORS decapitate LIZARD!")
                $("#winner").text("You WIN!")
            break

            default:
                $("#end").css("display", "inline")
                $("#outcome").text("SPOCK smashes SCISSORS!")
                $("#winner").text("You LOSE!")
        }
    }
    else if (userChoice === "lizard") 
    {
        switch(compChoice) 
        {
            case "rock":
                $("#end").css("display", "inline")
                $("#outcome").text("ROCK crushes LIZARD!")
                $("#winner").text("You LOSE!")
            break

            case "paper":
                $("#end").css("display", "inline")
                $("#outcome").text("LIZARD eats PAPER!")
                $("#winner").text("You WIN!")
            break

            case "scissors":
                $("#end").css("display", "inline")
                $("#outcome").text("SCISSORS decapitate LIZARD!")
                $("#winner").text("You LOSE!")
            break

            default:
                $("#end").css("display", "inline")
                $("#outcome").text("LIZARD poisons SPOCK!")
                $("#winner").text("You WIN!")
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        switch(compChoice)
        {
            case "rock":
                $("#end").css("display", "inline")
                $("#outcome").text("SPOCK vaporizes ROCK!")
                $("#winner").text("You WIN!")
            break

            case "paper":
                $("#end").css("display", "inline")
                $("#outcome").text("PAPER disproves SPOCK!")
                $("#winner").text("You LOSE!")
            break

            case "scissors":
                $("#end").css("display", "inline")
                $("#outcome").text("SPOCK smashes SCISSORS!")
                $("#winner").text("You WIN!")
            break

            default:
                $("#end").css("display", "inline")
                $("#outcome").text("LIZARD poisons SPOCK!")
                $("#winner").text("You LOSE!")
        }  
    }
})
```

Comment: That would definitely make things easier! Thanks, I'm going to try it out.

Comment: Cool... if all goes well, don't forget to mark as correct answer for future readers... and me of course ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle that solves your problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/tw8wgwn3/

There were a couple issues. First, the userChoice and compChoice could not be seen outside the click() functions, this could be handled by declaring them outside of the functions or creating new functions to pass them into - which is probably the better solution. The second issue is the JavaScript to assign the value has already run by the time the user clicks an image. By creating new functions you can solve both issues at the same time.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//What img does when mouse hovers on it
$("img").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).css("height", "10em");
    $(this).css("width", "10em");
    $("selector").css("cursor", "pointer");
});
$("img").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).css("height", "8em");
    $(this).css("width", "8em");
});



//Assigning values to userChoice (click on an img!)
$('.rock').click(function() {
    var userChoice = "rock";
    var compChoice = Math.random();
    checkCompChoice(compChoice);
    assignCompChoice(compChoice, userChoice);
});

$('.paper').click(function() {
    var userChoice = "paper";
    var compChoice = Math.random();
    checkCompChoice(compChoice);
    assignCompChoice(compChoice, userChoice);
});  

$('.scissors').click(function() {
    var userChoice = "scissors";
    var compChoice = Math.random();
    checkCompChoice(compChoice);
    assignCompChoice(compChoice, userChoice);
});    

$('.lizard').click(function() {
    var userChoice = "lizard";
    var compChoice = Math.random();
    checkCompChoice(compChoice);
    assignCompChoice(compChoice, userChoice);
});    

$('.spock').click(function() {
    var userChoice = "rock";
    var compChoice = Math.random();
    checkCompChoice(compChoice);
    assignCompChoice(compChoice, userChoice);
});

function checkCompChoice(compChoice){
    if (compChoice <= 0.20) {
        compChoice = "rock";
    } else if(compChoice <= 0.40) {
        compChoice = "paper";
    } else if(compChoice <= 0.60) {
        compChoice = "scissors";
    } else if(compChoice <= 0.80) {
        compChoice = "lizard";
    } else {
        compChoice = "spock";
    }
}
//Assign compChoice
function assignCompChoice(compChoice, userChoice){
    if (userChoice === compChoice) {
    $("#end").css("display", "inline");
    $("#outcome").text(userChoice + " against " + compChoice + " ?");
    $("#winner").text("It's a tie!");
    }
    else if (userChoice === "rock") {
        if (compChoice === "paper") {
            $("#end").css("display", "inline");
            $("#outcome").text("PAPER covers ROCK!");
            $("#winner").text("You LOSE!");
        }
        else if (compChoice === "scissors") {
            $("#end").css("display", "inline");
            $("#outcome").text("ROCK crushes SCISSORS!");
            $("#winner").text("You WIN!");
        }
        else if (compChoice === "lizard") {
            $("#end").css("display", "inline");
            $("#outcome").text("ROCK crushes LIZARD!");
            $("#winner").text("You WIN!");
        }
        else {
            $("#end").css("display", "inline");
            $("#outcome").text("SPOCK vaporizes ROCK!");
            $("#winner").text("You LOSE!");
        }
    }
    else if (userChoice === "paper") {
        if (compChoice === "rock") {
            $("#end").css("display", "inline");
            $("#outcome").text("PAPER covers ROCK!");
            $("#winner").text("You WIN!");
        }
        else if (compChoice === "scissors") {
            $("#end").css("display", "inline");
            $("#outcome").text("SCISSORS cuts PAPER!");
            $("#winner").text("You LOSE!");
        }
        else if (compChoice === "lizard") {
            $("#end").css("display", "inline");
            $("#outcome").text("LIZARD eats PAPER!");
            $("#winner").text("You LOSE!");
        }
        else {
            $("#end").css("display", "inline");
            $("#outcome").text("PAPER disproves SPOCK!");
            $("#winner").text("You WIN!");
        }
    }
    else if (userChoice === "scissors") {
        if (compChoice === "rock") {
            $("#end").css("display", "inline");
            $("#outcome").text("ROCK crushes SCISSORS!");
            $("#winner").text("You LOSE!");
        }
        else if (compChoice === "paper") {
            $("#end").css("display", "inline");
            $("#outcome").text("SCISSORS cuts PAPER!");
            $("#winner").text("You WIN!");
        }
        else if (compChoice === "lizard") {
            $("#end").css("display", "inline");
            $("#outcome").text("SCISSORS decapitate LIZARD!");
            $("#winner").text("You WIN!");
        }
        else {
            $("#end").css("display", "inline");
            $("#outcome").text("SPOCK smashes SCISSORS!");
            $("#winner").text("You LOSE!");
        }
    }
    else if (userChoice === "lizard") {
        if (compChoice === "rock") {
            $("#end").css("display", "inline");
            $("#outcome").text("ROCK crushes LIZARD!");
            $("#winner").text("You LOSE!");
        }
        else if (compChoice === "paper") {
            $("#end").css("display", "inline");
            $("#outcome").text("LIZARD eats PAPER!");
            $("#winner").text("You WIN!");
        }
        else if (compChoice === "scissors") {
            $("#end").css("display", "inline");
            $("#outcome").text("SCISSORS decapitate LIZARD!");
            $("#winner").text("You LOSE!");
        }
        else {
            $("#end").css("display", "inline");
            $("#outcome").text("LIZARD poisons SPOCK!");
            $("#winner").text("You WIN!");
        }
    }
    else {
        if (compChoice === "rock") {
            $("#end").css("display", "inline");
            $("#outcome").text("SPOCK vaporizes ROCK!");
            $("#winner").text("You WIN!");
        }
        else if (compChoice === "paper") {
            $("#end").css("display", "inline");
            $("#outcome").text("PAPER disproves SPOCK!");
            $("#winner").text("You LOSE!");
        }
        else if (compChoice === "scissors") {
            $("#end").css("display", "inline");
            $("#outcome").text("SPOCK smashes SCISSORS!");
            $("#winner").text("You WIN!");
        }
        else {
            $("#end").css("display", "inline");
            $("#outcome").text("LIZARD poisons SPOCK!");
            $("#winner").text("You LOSE!");
        }    
    };
    }
});
```